# Сортировка многомерного массива с выбором ключас сортировки

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток всем.
есть такой массивчик

```
    Array(
    array(
       'name' => 'title 1',
       'price' => '200'
       'order' => '8'
    )
    array(
       'name' => 'title 2',
       'price' => '100'
       'order' => '3'
    )
    ...
)
```

сортировка по ключу 'price'

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return ($a['price'] - $b['price']);
});
```

До сих пор все понятно, все работает.

Вопрос - как в usort закинуть ключ сортировки????

то-есть нужна возможность принудительно задавать параметром сам ключ, по которому будет происходить сортировка - или 'name', или 'price', или 'order' ..............

Критично -> php 5.6 - не выше,  тапками не кидайте, помидорами тоже. Поднять версию php не реально   в этом несчастном случае.

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/t201YR

```
<?php

$array = array(
  array(
   'name' => 'title 1',
   'price' => 200,
   'order' => 8
  ),
  array(
   'name' => 'title 2',
   'price' => 100,
   'order' => 3
  )
);

function sortBy(&$arr, $field) {
  return usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($field) {
    return $a[$field] - $b[$field];
  });
}

sortBy($array, 'price');
var_dump($array);

sortBy($array, 'order');
var_dump($array);
```